# AngularJs clear global variable

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a global variable to communicate with external javascript. So I use

```
window.report = $scope.myData  // my scope with all data
```

The problem is when I try to run othe report I should first reset this global variable and then fill it again.

I have tried with:

```
window.report = null;

window.report = {};
```

But old data is still there if no new data to overwrite....

Could be this a partial template cache that causes the problem?

I have tried to log on console the window.report variable and is undefined. So the problem should be elsewhere...

[UPDATE]

The problem here is probably a Service.

```
app.factory('Report', ['$http', function($http,$q){

var Reports = {

    reports : {},

    requests :[{'url':'getReport','response':'Analizing page','count':1},
               {'url':'getPagerank','response':'Getting 1','count':2},
               {'url':'getRobots','response':'Getting 2','count':3},
               {'url':'getIpCanonicalization','response':'Gwetting 3','count':4}]

              ]

};

Reports.getReport = function(target, source, response, callback) {
    return $http({  url:"/seo/getter/", 
                    method:"POST", 
                    //cache: true,
                    params:{"url" : target, "action": source}
                }).success(function(result) {
                    callback(result);
                    console.log(Reports.reports)
                    jQuery.extend(true,Reports.reports, result.data)
                    //console.log($scope.user)
                }).error(function(error){
                    callback(result);
                    jQuery.extend(true,Reports.reports, result.data)
                })
}

    Reports.startQueue = function (target, callback) {
        var promises = [];
        this.requests.forEach(function (obj, i) {
            promises.push(Reports.getReport(target, obj.url, obj.response, function(response,reports){
                callback(obj.response,Reports.reports,obj.count)
            }));
        });
    }

return Reports;
}])
```

I think that Reports.reports var still contain old data when I try to update my view. So the problem should not be the global bvariable, but a service that still grab previous data. How can I be sure that Report.reports is empty when I update?

Comment: try in the angular code $window doing so you get access to the the window object by angular.You could try constant as well

Comment: Always tried!! Could be a cache problem?

Comment: try to post more code

Comment: This is a very large app, I really cannot post all the code. I will try to create a fiddle...

Comment: Please check out [this Plunker script](http://plnkr.co/edit/wVoXFATDegnwZjSK4GDZ?p=preview). Everything seems to work just fine.

Comment: @MichaelBenford Your code is correct, and so should be mine. But really cannot understand why my partial display also old data...

Comment: Are you triggering a digest-loop after making changes to $scope variables? Angular uses dirty-checking to know when it needs to repaint but if you're making changes from "outside" it won't know that it needs to do it. You can trigger it manually with $scope.$digest();

Comment: @ivarni where I should make $scope.digest? in the service or after I set the window var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved adding a new function to my service, and after all process I reset my service var:

```
    Reports.resetReports = function () {
        Reports.reports = {};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use window just don't put var in front of it. Also you can't tech delete a global variable ever that's just basic javascript.